# C# - Can't find file when part of path string from DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, path

Ok my problem is, when i try to access a file while the Filename of the path is from a DataTable it just can't find the file.

I already tested it when i parse the Filename from a textfile or just hardcode in the string...and ofcourse this work >_<

Just dont get where the diff is when i string the filename from the DataTable.

The string it build look like this:

**C:\Server\system/somefile.dat**

Here is the code:

```
    string accountConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstring"].ConnectionString;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadFileChecks();
    }

    public SqlConnection GetAccountConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(accountConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }


    public DataTable getFilecheck()
    {
        using (var con = GetAccountConnection())
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tFilecheck", con);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable("Filecheck");
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            return ds;
        }
    }

    public void LoadFileChecks()
    {
        DataTable table = getFilecheck();
        string localPath = Application.StartupPath;

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            string line = row["sFilename"].ToString();

            string FilePath = localPath + "\\" + line;
            if (!File.Exists(FilePath))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File not found");
                continue;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Instead of manually trying to concatenate the paths and file names and munge the double slashes, look up the method [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx), which does the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: OK tried that, string look like that now: "C:\\Server\\system\\somefile.dat" but still cant find file :<

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `Application.StartupPath` is depends on how you deploy application exe.

```
string localPath = Application.StartupPath;
```

will be current execution path when debug (eg. project\bin\Debug)

Second, You don't need escape every backslash with `\\`

for sample, instead of..

```
string path = "C:\\Server\\system";
```

try escape string with `@`

```
string path = @"C:\Server\system";
```

then Path.Combine with file name

```
string fileName = row["sFilename"].ToString();
string filePath = Path.Combine(path, fileName); 
//Path.Combine(@"C:\Server\system", "somefile.dat");
```

Comment: the localpath is the "C:\\Server" and it get "system\somefile.dat" from the datatable. The  string it build is "C:\\Server\\system\\somefile.dat" wich look fine for me, but it just wont work somehow...this happen only when i get the file path from the database >_< gettin it from textfile or hardcode work fine..

Answer (score 0):

Is this a .net web application ? if yes, you should change the path to server path using

```
path = Server.MapPath(path);
```

Comment: nah this one is winforms, and it build the string right way..just cant see the file somehow